# PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsql-package

I have a oracle package and there is a function in it which is having out parameters.

the package name lets say ppp and function name lets say fff.
function is below and i am unable to execute the function with out parameters.

function-

```
FUNCTION  fff (P_FID NUMBER,DUCTBANKLABEL VARCHAR2, SERVICEDUCTVALID OUT NUMBER ) RETURN VARCHAR2
----End of R3 - Obs#195 (1 Oct 2018)
AS

CNT NUMBER;
INSTDATE VARCHAR2(100);
DUCTSIZE NUMBER;
.
.
.
.
many more.......;
BEGIN
.
.
.function does its thing and returns the value

END;
```

Now am trying to call this function with a pl/sql block like this-

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
aa NUMBER:=129685933;
bb VARCHAR2:='1705297E TO P5547635';
cc  NUMBER;
ANS VARCHAR2;
BEGIN
ANS:=ppp.fff(aa,bb,cc);
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(ANS);
END;
```

But getting the below error-

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 4:
PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)
ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Please help on how can i execute this function

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify `VARCHAR2` variable lengths in your anonymous PL/SQL block.

```sql
DECLARE
    aa    NUMBER := 129685933;
    bb    VARCHAR2 (30) := '1705297E TO P5547635';
    cc    NUMBER;
    ANS   VARCHAR2 (200);
BEGIN
    ANS := ppp.fff (aa, bb, cc);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (ANS);
END;
```

Comment: am just a starter so missed it completely ..its fine now but when the run the block instead of printing the output it says "anonymous block completed"..any idea what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

`varchar2` variables need to have a length as the error indicates.

Line 3

```
bb VARCHAR2:='1705297E TO P5547635';
```

and line 5

```
ANS VARCHAR2;
```

are both missing lengths.  Assuming you want both to allow, say, 100 characters

```
bb VARCHAR2(100):='1705297E TO P5547635';
ANS VARCHAR2(100);
```

Comment: am just a starter so missed it completely ..its fine now but when the run the block instead of printing the output it says "anonymous block completed"..any idea what can i do?

Comment: @TheSacredKiller - You've tagged this for SQL Developer and PL/SQL Developer, two totally different GUI tools.  Which one are you actually using to execute your code?  If you are trying to see something written to `dbms_output`, you may need to enable that in your GUI.

Comment: i am using sql developer...oracle 12 c

Comment: PL/SQL is a server process that has no ability to write to the client's screen.  As such, dbms_output does _not_ write to the screen but to a buffer that is returned to the client _upon completion of the procedure_.  It is then up to the client program to process (or ignore) that buffer.  As @JustinCave said, you my need to enable it in your GUI.  Or, if you are using sqlplus, you issue the _sqlplus command_ 'set serverout on' before executing the procedure.

Comment: @TheSacredKiller - I removed the PL/SQL Developer tag on the question then.  In SQL Developer, if you go to View | DBMS Output, that will open the DBMS Output window.  You'd want to click on the green plus icon in that window to enable DBMS Output for the session.

Comment: @TheSacredKiller - SQL Developer is about 98% compatible with SQL\*Plus. In particular, instead of navigating menus to enable screen output, you can also issue the SQL\*Plus command directly, in the editor window, before running the anonymous block. The command is `set serveroutput on` as shown already.

Comment: i tried serveroutput on and also as Justin and Stevens told enabling DBMS_OUTPUT from view but it still says "anonymous block completed"..

Comment: @TheSacredKiller - Are you sure that there is something to print out?  Perhaps the function is returning a NULL value or a string of all spaces or something else.

Comment: let me put a string and then the variable and see if its printing the string or not

Comment: yeah i guess it doesn't qualify the conditions inside the function body...its a big 300 line function and need to check authenticity of data. Anyways, thank you everyone for your help. appreciate it.

Comment: Sounds like it would be helpful to run it through the debugger so you can watch it step by step.